# Lines in Mapbox tilesets not rendering correctly

Tags: mapbox, geojson, overpass-api

I recently updated my tilesets for a project in Mapbox, but with the new ones, at certain zooms, parts of the lines simply disappear completely, both on the tileset preview and on the style itself. It even happens when I re-uploaded my old tilesets which worked perfectly before...
They are all geojson data, here is a example if you can access it : clemapbox.7m7v5xg0 .

This is really annoying and I don't know what to do about, even changing to old data I used didn't work, I still have missing parts of lines...

(And also I can simply not upload some geojson files that are directly from overpass, I don't know why).

Hope someone can help

Thanks !

EDIT : screenshots
[image: first screenshot]
[image: second screenshot]
[image: third screenshot]
[image: details]

Comment: Hey there! Mind giving a bit more details? Specifically, do lines disappear at high zoom levels (when zooming way in)? What do the tilesets say is the max zoom on them (when you view the tileset, on the right hand side). For the geoJSONs, if you can provide a JSBIn or something with the geoJSONs, I can analyze them.

Comment: Yes : at low zoom, it's ok, but parts of some lines disappear (and sometimes reappear) when I zoom in. Max zoom is 16 or 17, but the issue is here at lower zoom than that. I will try to reproduce this with a smaller dataset for the geojson and maybe send it or paste it.

Comment: (about the geoJSON, I just spent half an hour trying to find what part in my 10 MB file doesnt work. Turs out I can "split" it into pieces that work (I cut it in the way I download the data) but I can't upload it when I have all the data... quite strange)

Comment: Okay, so you're pretty sure this isn't a zoom extent issue? Check my video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jjbuqv4QAcE . Often you'll need to modify zoom extent on geoJSONs to make sure all the geometries appear as expected.

Comment: No it's not because as you can see, it does't affect the whole tile set at one time but only parts of some lines. Also the zoom extent is 11-17 but it breaks within this range

Comment: I believe I have had this happen with individual features on geoJSONs, and it was still a zoom extent issue. Could you place the geoJSONs somewhere so I could experiment with them directly?

Comment: Ok here is a small set which has the same issue for me (but zoom extent 0-21 on Mapbox): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-lhxrbxzdjeUnXFGiWN7IQKbnxh2dx3Z/view?usp=sharing